# Why does moving classes into a new folder in Visual Studio break things?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET application with three areas.  In the root of the application is a Models folder containing a hodgepodge of classes, including two DataContexts, some Repository classes, some ViewModel classes, some helper classes, and some business logic classes.

I'd like to create subfolders for each of these subcategories and move the associated files into the appropriate subfolder.  However, I am noticing that this is breaking things.  For example, if I move one of the DataContexts to a DataContext subfolder in the Models folder, I find that the code in the repositories can no longer see the DataContext type.

Which must mean that the Models folder has special meaning to the system.  What am I missing here?  Is there some way to "sensitize" the subfolders so that the other code can still see the implemented classes and namespaces?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a namespacing issue?  The model folder has no special meaning.

The ASP.NET MVC team has said something like before:

"*The only reason the model folder exists is because people kept asking us where to put our model classes*"  ;)

Comment: But I haven't changed any of the namespaces.  All I did was create a new folder under Models, and drag the DataContext.dbml into that folder.

Comment: You may have not changed namespacee but VS could be trying to be helpful by renaming things for you.  I've seen that happen before.

Comment: You are correct; VS changed the namespace when I moved the file. Grf, what a pain. How do you turn that off?

Comment: Looks like it only does this with the DataContext objects anyway (so far). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  This might be OK behavior if Visual Studio asked you if you wanted to do a global rename first.

Answer (score 1):

When you drag and drop your files and folder, it will move the the files, but the namespaces are not updated, thus your code will break. One way is to create new file/folder and copy your code - which is a bit tedious but right way.
Another way is to use Resharper - Ctrl+Shift R, which lets you move the file and also updates the namespaces and your code will not break.
I am finding a faster way to do the same without Resharper, and when I do I will update my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: You do know that you're posting an answer on an eight-year-old question, right?

Comment: Yes, I do! :) Posting it here in hope that someone else might benefit from it. By the way if you are aware how to do it without a tool like Resharper, please share - which will really help.

Comment: I haven't had this problem at all in Visual Studio 2017, so maybe the problem was specific to Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Taking my first steps in C# I came across this post...
in VS 2019 if you `refactor->move` the class file you have options to move to another location

[image]